# Get future date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the date which is 14th of January,2014 in Javascript but it is returning invalid date.

```
var clock;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.setFullYear(2014,17,1) + 1, 0, 1);
    alert(futureDate);
});
```

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/zJF35/

Comment: That's plain Javascript, not jQuery, except for the `$(document.ready()` part.

Comment: Your code does not match up with the JSFiddle example. Please change either.

Comment: `setFullYear` only takes one argument, why are you giving it 3?

Comment: The fiddle is fixed up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zJF35/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `var futureDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 14);`

Answer (score 1):

[setFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) method sets the full year for a specified date according to local time.

```
dateObj.setFullYear(yearValue[, monthValue[, dayValue]])
```

here the middle one parameter is month value in which you are passing `17` which is not making sense and its converting into next year.

So You probably want this

```
var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.setFullYear(2014,0,14));
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zJF35/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var futureDate = new Date(2014,0,14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any future date in JavaScript (postman test uses JavaScript) can be retrieved as:

```
var dateNow = new Date();  
var twoWeeksFutureDate = new Date(dateNow.setDate(dateNow.getDate() + 14)).toISOString();
```

//Note it returns 2 weeks future date from now.